# http:// links getting changed to // wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

On my WordPress site all the http:// links that I add are getting changed to //.

For example `<a href="http://www.examplesite.com"></a>` Is getting changed to `<a href="//www.examplesite.com"></a>` when I load the page.

In the text edit mode in my wordpress editor the correct code is shown but in the browser console the code shows up without the http: in the link.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Links starting with `//` are not internal

Comment: what would cause the http: to be stripped from the link?

Comment: How do you see that links are stripped? In a source html? Maybe you have some javascript on a client which does this?

Comment: I can see the html of the page from the browser console

Comment: Actually that tends to be considered good practise as it's agnostic of a specific transfer method eg: the link is valid as both http and https.